# How we can dynamically change this @ClientIDCode with @CodeMask string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How we can dynamically change this `@ClientIDCode` with `@CodeMask` string in SQL Server?

```
DECLARE @ClientIDCode varchar(20) = '1000003351', @CodeMask VARCHAR(50) = 'XXX-XXX'
DECLARE @ClientIDCode varchar(20) = '1000003351', @CodeMask VARCHAR(50) = 'XX-XXXX'
DECLARE @ClientIDCode varchar(20) = '1000003351', @CodeMask VARCHAR(50) = 'XX&XXXX'
```

I want an output like this:

```
1000003-351
100000-3351
100000&3351
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but perhaps `format()` could help here.  Notice `BIGINT` and `#'s`

**Example**

```
 DECLARE @ClientIDCode bigint = 1000003351, @CodeMask VARCHAR(50) = '###-###'
 Select format(@ClientIDCode,@codeMask)
```

**Results**

```
1000003-351
```

**Image for Larnu**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this'll be more performant that John's using `FORMAT` (which is a known poor performer) but it doesn't involve changing the data types. You could split the strings into it's individual characters and then string aggregate, replacing non-X characters with the mask:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE SS.M WHEN 'X' THEN SS.C ELSE SS.M END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY V.I DESC)
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20))V(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@ClientIDCode),V.I,1),ISNULL(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@CodeMask), V.I,1),''),'X')))SS(C,M)
WHERE SS.C != '';
```

This *assumes* `@ClientIDCode` can't be longer than 20 characters (as you define it as a `varchar(20)`). If it can be longer, then use an inline tally.

This also *assumes* you are on a supported version of SQL Server, as you haven't mentioned you aren't.

---

After testing, this is more performant on both my local host, work sandbox, and [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d06f119c18d9beea37155a6163fb441).

Comment: Surely you don't believe ONE format() call is less performant than the above.

Comment: I didn't say I believe that, @JohnCappelletti . I clearly say otherwise: *"I'm not sure if this'll be more performant that John's"* I didn't test to check

Comment: Now, on the over hand, @JohnCappelletti, I'll correct my statement to say **it is** more performant. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d06f119c18d9beea37155a6163fb441). As I mentioned, `FORMAT` is a well known poor performer.

Comment: Format() is unjustly maligned.  I'm the first to admit that it should be used sparingly due to the performance issue, but it does have some useful functionality.   To be clear, I ran your dbFiddle on dbFiddle and I got 296891900 (mine) vs 421890500 (yours)

Comment: Do you have a link to said fiddle, @JohnCappelletti ? Apart from once (which was after the first time running the linked fiddle on this comment locally), I have not managed to get a lower number using your solution (and i've probably reran the queries about 30+ times at this stage). I even tried with the column as a `bigint` to start with, [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ce58a41a5ed792b5a1096394725533e), which removes the cost of the `CONVERT` but still results in longer run times (apart from aforementioned first run locally).

Comment: I added an image to my answer

Comment: Honestly, after the amount of times i've run it, I'd put it to the same anomaly I mentioned above, @JohnCappelletti . I didn't just run this once before making the claim. I tested on multiple instances.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm not doubting you.  My point is this.  Format() is just another option... another tool in the belt.  We don't know OP's use case.  Could be 10K rows or it could be 1 string.   If one string, I would opt for format (I'm more valuable than a few CPU cycles).  If >10K, I may consider other options like STUFF().   Performance is not the only consideration.

Comment: I don't disagree, @JohnCappelletti , I think that's why it's good we have such different solutions.